# Search SQL using JSON Raw data Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to search sql data from raw that hold json data. I am trying to search query by using REGEX but its not working and I also want to know is there is a smart way to do that please tell me.

"Riyaz" is value I want - exact value to make sure it search only that keyword.

```php
    $customerlist=Customer::where("group", "REGEXP", '^Riyaz$')
       ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
       ->get();

// DB JSON = {"name":["Riyaz","Saifi"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `whereJsonContains` query operator to perform a search on a JSON object:

```php
$customersList = Customer::whereJsonContains('group->name', 'Riyaz')
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```